# Incompatible types: int and <nulltype>

Tags: java, types, null, int

I am having trouble with the (hashTable[bucket][size] == null). I was wondering how you could check to see that slot is null if null is not of type int. Any ideas/tips?

```
public void add(int n){
   int bucket = hashF(n);
   int p=0;
   int size = hashTable[0].length;
  for(int i=0; i>size; i++){
    if(hashTable[bucket][size] == null){
      hashTable[bucket][size]= n;
      break;
    }
    if(i+1 == size){
      bucket++;
      i = -1;
    }
    if(bucket ==10){
      bucket = 0;
    }
    p++;
    if(p== hashTable.length*hashTable[0].length){
      break;
    }
  }
  for(int i=0; i<BST.length; i++){
    if(BST[i] == null){
      BST[i] = n;
      break;
    }
    else if(n<BST[i]){
      i= 2*i;
    }
    else{
        i = 2*i+1;
      }
  }
 }
```

Comment: It doesn't look like `hashtable[bucket][size]` can actually be null. Why are you checking that? *Should* it be something that can be null?

Comment: "I was wondering how you could check to see that slot is null if null is not of type int." You can't, because that's never the case. Either use something nullable (which, in Java, means you must use a non-primitive type; `Integer`, perhaps?), or find a different solution that doesn't involve null.

Comment: So does that mean we have to make it a generic class to check to see if that specific slot as nothing int it?

Comment: If using a "sentinel" `int` value isn't an option (i.e. all `ints` are valid in your hash table), then there really isn't a whole lot you can do beyond moving to `Integer` (or making your hash table generic)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that hashTable is a 2D array of ints, you cannot check if one of its elements will be null as it never will be. A primitive can never be null as it is not an object reference. It will always have a value - its default value is 0.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 0):

Java primitives (like `int`) have no "unassigned" value - they *always* have a value.

If you want to represent "unassigned" use an "impossible" value for the size, such as `-1` which you would assign at initialization. Then in code test for `hashTable[bucket][size] == -1` to determine if it's in it's initial state.

Comment: We are allowed to add negative numbers into the hashTable.

Comment: What exactly is the definition of hashTable - please show that code.

Comment: hashTable =  new int[10][size];
I think is what you're asking for